# How to print a circle shape image with RDLC report in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I am displaying an image in the RDLC report from the Database. I've loaded the image inside an Image component from Toolbox. Currently, the image box is box shape by default and printing in box shape as well. I want the image to be printed in a circle shape. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<Border/>` to make rounded edges on your Image. I don't think you can directly make the Image component rounded.
Another way is to set the Image as the `Background` of the `Border` and set the `CornerRadius` to half his size.

Like that:

```
<Border Height="100" Width="100" CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="3">
   <Border.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="pupy.jpg"/>
   </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: I want to apply your suggested process, I have this
`<Image Name="Image1">
  <Source>Database</Source>
  <Value>=Parameters!image.Value</Value>
  <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
  <Sizing>Fit</Sizing>
  <Top>0.50909in</Top>
  <Left>0.5055in</Left>
  <Height>1.36458in</Height>
  <Width>1.44569in</Width>
  <Style>
    <Border>
      <Color>PaleTurquoise</Color>
      <Style>None</Style>
    </Border>
  </Style>
</Image>`
any way to do it from UI in Visual Studio?

Comment: Your `<Border>` need to be the father element of the Image, then you can set a `CornerRadius` property and It will appear inside the circler border. You should be able to modify the `CornerRadius` in the `Appearance` tab in the `Properties` window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an empty circle with border line that is vector, you enter letter O (O from Opera) and use font style: Centry Gothic. It will create the desired circle.